# duplicate when sending email through swiftmail

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I try to send email using swiftmailer the problem is, it send duplicate email (usually more than 3 mails) in same time, it only happen in my server (my local is fine though), first I think it because setting in my server and local is different but I don't find anything fishy, for your information my server running in ubuntu and my local run in xampp windows. please give me suggestion how to solve this